# Distribute $x$ different balls into $k$ boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I know that for distributing n balls in k boxes, the formula is

${n+k-1}\choose{n}$

But this is for indistinguishable balls. I tried to figure out the formula for different balls but couldn't figure it out, any help?

Comment: Hint: $k$ possible boxes for the first ball, $k$ possible boxes for the second ball, ... for the $n$th ball

Comment: This amounts to picking boxes for the balls to go into, where order matters. So you are just doing permutations with repetitions on the boxes.